# MySQL - logging errors into

Tags: mysql

If I look into

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

there is set this file:

```
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

But this file doesn't exist - when I try to create the **mysql** directory, where would be the **error.log** file, I get error that there already exist a file **mysql**.

How can I set the file logging errors for MySQL?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`` actually contains the configuration that your mysql server uses?

Comment: In the mysql client, run `show global variables like 'log_error';`. It will show you which error file is effectively used.

Comment: Richard, it shows `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. But when `cat /var/log/mysql/error.log`, it returns `cat: /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied`. If I do `cd /var/log/mysql`, then it returns: `-bash: cd: /var/log/mysql: Permission denied` - how to fix the permissions?

Comment: MySQL was probably installed using the mysql account, and you are using a different account to connect to the system.

You can confirm this using `ls -ld /var/log/mysql` and `ls -l /var/logg/mysql`to view the permissions on the folder and on the log file. 

Once confirmed, you can either change permissions to the log file (including giving read access to group and adding your account to the mysql group),  or use the mysql account to access the log. Which of the two solution is preferable depends on security requirements.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. `ls -ld /var/log/mysql` -> `drwxr-s--- 2 mysql adm 4096 Dec 20 07:35 /var/log/mysql` and `ls -l /var/log/mysql` -> `ls: cannot open directory /var/log/mysql: Permission denied`. Yes, I use `my_db_name` to access database for my application. What's the recommended way to extend the permissions for `my_db_name`? Thank you